# Why Same where clause need to write multiple times in a Linq Query for following SQL

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

What will be the proper linq syntax of below SQL Query ?

```
select a.id, a.AppointmentStatusID, ad.ID as DetailID
from [dbo].[Appointment] a, [dbo].[AppointmentDetail] ad
where a.[ID] = ad.[AppointmentID]
and a.CompanyID = 'a3dea87a-804e-4115-98cf-472988cf1678'
and a.LocationID = '3165caca-2a48-46f0-bbed-578cff29167t'
and ad.AppDateFrom <= {ts '2017-11-14 23:59:31'}
and ad.AppDateTo >= {ts '2017-11-14 00:00:00'}
and ad.[ApprovalStatusID] = 2
```

**Problem I faced:**

I required to filter Where Condition *two times* **1st** at the time within the join & **2nd** time during the object.Select expression, please check bellow

```
var results = (from a in appointments
                                   join ad in _appointmentDetailRepository.GetAll() on a.ID equals ad.AppointmentID
                                   where ad.ApprovalStatusID == 2
                                   && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ad.AppDateFrom) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(viewmodel.AppointmentDate)
                                   && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ad.AppDateTo) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(viewmodel.AppointmentDate)
                                   orderby a.ID
                                   select new Appointment
                                   {
                                       ID = a.ID,
                                       CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
                                       LocationID = a.LocationID,
                                       AppointmentDetail = a.AppointmentDetail.Select(ad => new AppointmentDetail
                                       {
                                           ID = ad.ID,
                                           AppDateFrom = ad.AppDateFrom,
                                           AppDateTo = ad.AppDateTo,
                                           AppointmentStatusID = ad.AppointmentStatusID,
}).Where(ad=> ad.ApprovalStatusID == 2
                                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ad.AppDateFrom) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(viewmodel.AppointmentDate)
                                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ad.AppDateTo) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(viewmodel.AppointmentDate)).ToList()
 }).GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => x.DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault());
```

**Query** : Why I required to write Where clause 2 times ?

**Required Result**

An Appointment Object --> Containing `ICollection<AppoinmentDetails>` if Details.Where Condition == True

Comment: This is basically an (inner) join. Do you see specific problems? ( ´var query =
    from ad in AppointmentDetail
    join a in Appointment on a.ID == ad.AppointmentID where ..... (easy) select new { id = a.ID, ... etc }´

Comment: @thmshd: I update my post.

Comment: Instead of join, use navigation properties. though the query with join is not too complicated either, the one with navigation property is even simpler (pretty much 3 line of codes with appropriate readability)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: Can you please explain in linq code snippet.

Comment: The query you could use with navigation property would be something like var appointment=appointments.Where(x=>x.AppointmentDetail!=null&&x.CompanyId="..."&&x.LocationId="..."&&x.AppointmentDetail.AppDateFrom<=...&&x.AppointmentDetail.AppDateTo>=...).Select(x=>new{Id=x.Id, AppointmentStatusId=x.AppointmentStatusId, DetailId=x.AppointmentDetail.Id}).ToList();

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: `x.AppointmentDetail.‌​AppDateFrom` not possible as because it is a `ICollection<AppointmentDetail>` only way using `FirstOrDefault()` or relevant. But it will not return expected result

Comment: in that case you can't get around the use of the .Join method I think, which will flatten the resulting object graph for you. However, there you should use two .Where statements to be as close to the query plan as possible. Something like appointments.Where().Join(db.AppointmentDetail,(x,y)=>x.Id==y.AppointmentId,(x,y)=>new{x.Id, x.AppointmentStatusId, y.AppDateFrom, ...}.Where(...).Select(...)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro: don't you think `from a in appointments
                                   join ad in _appointmentDetailRepository.GetAll()....` this part of my existing query represent the same thing as you suggest. If I am wrong , please correct me. Because `appointments` is actually result set of 1st `Where` clause as you described `appointments.Where()`

Comment: You should remove the join completely from the LINQ query. You're already using `a.AppointmentDetail` which will be translated to a SQL `JOIN`.

Comment: @GertArnold: I updated my post

Comment: I rolled back your last two revisions because you shouldn't change the questions when answers have been given.  The answers apply to the current version of your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see (without knowing the model you have), it looks like you should use the already joined and filtered Details from `ad` instead of looking it up again from the Property `a.AppointmentDetail`...

Untested:

```
select new Appointment
{
    ID = a.ID,
    CompanyID = a.CompanyID,
    LocationID = a.LocationID,
    AppointmentDetail = ad.ToList(), // <-- don't you think?
    ...
}
```

Comment: the problem if I don't write 2nd where condition during AppointmentDetail = ad.where.ToList() it is not return exact result !! And I unable to understand why !!!!

Comment: I need to write this `AppointmentDetail =  a.AppointmentDetail.Select(ad => new AppointmentDetail { }` beacause both the object is different

Answer (score 0):

For the given SQL query

```
select a.id, a.AppointmentStatusID, ad.ID as DetailID
from [dbo].[Appointment] a, [dbo].[AppointmentDetail] ad
where a.[ID] = ad.[AppointmentID]
and a.CompanyID = 'a3dea87a-804e-4115-98cf-472988cf1678'
and a.LocationID = '3165caca-2a48-46f0-bbed-578cff29167t'
and ad.AppDateFrom <= {ts '2017-11-14 23:59:31'}
and ad.AppDateTo >= {ts '2017-11-14 00:00:00'}
and ad.[ApprovalStatusID] = 2
```

LINQ query can be written as

```
var results = (from a in appointments
                       join ad in appointmentDetails on a.ID equals ad.AppointmentID
                       where ad.ApprovalStatusID == 2
                           && a.CompanyID == "a3dea87a-804e-4115-98cf-472988cf1678"
                           && a.LocationID == "3165caca-2a48-46f0-bbed-578cff29167t"
                           && ad.AppDateFrom.Date <= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                           && ad.AppDateTo.Date >= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                       select new
                       {
                           ID = a.ID,
                           AppointmentStatusID = a.AppointmentStatusID,
                           DetailID = ad.ID
                       }).ToList();
```

You can also write it like

```
var results = appointmentDetails
                        .Where(ad => ad.AppDateFrom.Date <= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                                && ad.AppDateTo.Date >= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                                && ad.ApprovalStatusID == 2
                                && ad.Appointment.CompanyID == "a3dea87a-804e-4115-98cf-472988cf1678"
                                && ad.Appointment.LocationID == "3165caca-2a48-46f0-bbed-578cff29167t")
                        .Select(ad =>
                        new
                        {
                            ID = ad.Appointment.ID,
                            AppointmentStatusID = ad.Appointment.AppointmentStatusID,
                            DetailID = ad.ID
                        })
                        .ToList()
```

As per the updated question, to get the the Appointment object with a collection of AppointmentDetails, please try this query

```
var results = appointmentDetails
                        .Where(ad => ad.AppDateFrom.Date <= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                                && ad.AppDateTo.Date >= viewmodel.AppointmentDate.Date
                                && ad.ApprovalStatusID == 2
                                && ad.Appointment.CompanyID == "a3dea87a-804e-4115-98cf-472988cf1678"
                                && ad.Appointment.LocationID == "3165caca-2a48-46f0-bbed-578cff29167t")
                        .Select(ad =>
                        new
                        {
                            ID = ad.Appointment.ID,
                            AppointmentStatusID = ad.Appointment.AppointmentStatusID,
                            Detail = ad
                        })
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(a => new { a.ID, a.AppointmentStatusID })
                        .Select(a => new Appointment
                        {
                            ID = a.Key.ID,
                            AppointmentStatusID = a.Key.AppointmentStatusID,
                            AppointmentDetails = a.Select(d => d.Detail).ToList()
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but it is not giving the required result. Util I write a Second `Where` Clause during `AppointmentDetail = a.AppointmentDetail.Select`, I need to write it because to return specific Model not an `Anonymous` object

Comment: Confusion is that, why simple join clause in linq, not giving desired result. But in SQL we got desired result.

Comment: May I know your desired result and result that you are getting if you didn't add second where clause? How is it differing? Some sample data would do.

Comment: according to your modified query , your are query through Detail object and want to get relevant Appointment Model, few modification is needed in your query (1st) remove `.Date` property use `TruncateTime` otherwise you got error from Linq. (2nd) `Appointment = ad.Appointment,` add this to your 1st `select` , because I also want all the value of `Appointment Model` (3rd) Now put `CompanyID = a.FirstOrDefault().Appointment.CompanyID` in 2nd `select` And in this query format you need separate Join with `Appointment`, for  `PuprposeName` is a part of `Purpose`

Comment: Actually in the abode query format, you need to explicit join other object those are related to `Appointment` not with `AppointmentDetail`.